# How to assign a tf.placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My English is poor. I will try my best to clarify my question.

My inputs are various, [[1,2],[3,4]]  and  [[5,6],[7,8],[10,11]].
The outputs that I want are [[1,0,2,0],[3,0,4,0]]   and  [[5,0,6,0],[7,0,8,0],[10,0,11,0]]     (which means adding zeros between the numbers)

Here is my implemention:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
matrix1=[[1,2],[3,4]]
matrix2 = [[5,6],[7,8],[10,11]]
with tf.Session() as sess:
   input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
   output=how_to_add(input)
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   [matrix3] = sess.run([output], feed_dict={input:matrix1})
   print(matrix3)
```

the code about `how_to_add` is:

```
def how_to_add(input):
    shape = input.get_shape().as_list()
    output=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(([shape[0],4))
    with tf.control_dependencies([output[:,1::2].assign(input) ]): 
        output = tf.identity(output)
    return output
```

but `shape[0]` is `?`, so I got an error:

```
    "Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: %s" % s)
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?, 4)
```

### How to correct my codes?

supplementary:

These codes work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
matrix1=[[1,2],[3,4]]
matrix2 = [[5,6],[7,8],[10,11]]
with tf.Session() as sess:
   input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 2]) #'None' is repalced with '2'
   output=how_to_add(input)
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   [matrix3] = sess.run([output], feed_dict={input:matrix1})
   print(matrix3)
```

the code about how_to_add is:

```
def how_to_add(input):
    #shape = input.get_shape().as_list()
    output=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(([2,4)) # 'shape[0]' is replaced with '2'
    with tf.control_dependencies([output[:,1::2].assign(input) ]): 
        output = tf.identity(output)
    return output
```

Although these codes work, they can only deal with matrix1 rather than matrix2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use a variable for this, that is not their purpose. You should create a new tensor that is made from your input tensor. For your problem, you can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def interleave_zero_columns(matrix):
    # Add a matrix of zeros along a new third dimension
    a = tf.stack([matrix, tf.zeros_like(matrix)], axis=2)
    # Reshape to interleave zeros across columns
    return tf.reshape(a, [tf.shape(matrix)[0], -1])

# Test
matrix1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
matrix2 = [[5, 6], [7, 8], [10, 11]]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
    output = interleave_zero_columns(input)
    print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={input: matrix1}))
    # [[1. 0. 2. 0.]
    #  [3. 0. 4. 0.]]
    print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={input: matrix2}))
    # [[ 5.  0.  6.  0.]
    #  [ 7.  0.  8.  0.]
    #  [10.  0. 11.  0.]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified your code to adpat my task, and it works.